# Database Design for Paper Submission System

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-recommendation, relational-theory

I am learner of Database design, I want to design a database for a journal paper submission system in which one paper can be submitted by one or more author. I have initially two tables `Author` and `Paper`

Table `Author` has attributes like,

```
AuthorID
Name
Contact
Email
URL
```

Table `Paper` has attributes like

```
PaperID
Title
Abstract
Keywords
```

I need a third table `submission` where i can preserve association between paper and authors/author. Can any one help me in this regard to find possible association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is keep track of which authors contributed to which papers, then all you need is a simple **intersecting entity** (see [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)) like this:

[image: ERD1]

Here the columns of the `SUBMISSION` table are just the two primary key columns from `PAPER` and `AUTHOR`.  These two columns will jointly form the primary key of the intersecting table and will also each individually be foreign keys to their respective tables.

**NOTE:** Don't add any other columns to the `SUBMISSION` table, unless those columns can reasonably be expected to vary row by row for the same paper and for the same author.  For example, it would be a bad idea to add a date to the submission table unless a single paper is submitted at *various* times by *multiple* authors.  If you need to track information about the event of an author or group of authors submitting a paper, then you need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) out the extra information to avoid creating update anomalies.  Consider the following:

[image: ERD2]

In the above ERD, notice how the extra information that is not author-dependent remains at the `SUBMISSION` level, while the new intersecting entity `CONTRIBUTION` is added to record the connections between authors and a particular instance of the submission of a paper.

This four table model is more robust because it allows for papers to be resubmitted multiple times with changes in authorship each time.  If this kind of real world nuance is important to your system then you would be better off with the four table approach than with a three table approach.

Here is the four table model with more column details at OP's request:

[image: Detailed ERD]

Comment: Thank you so much Joel, you solved my 75% problem, I was confused in selection of foreign and primary keys your explanation helped me come out of that confusion. Thanks mate

Comment: Sir @Joel I understood ERD with 3 tables including Paper, Author, and Submission. But ERD with 4 tables is confusing me can you help plz to design the database with your suggested 4 tables ERD.

Comment: @IrfanAliMemon In the ERD with four tables, `SUBMISSION` records the act of a paper being submitted.  Assuming the editing process may sometimes involve rejection(s) and resubmission(s) this is 1:M with `PAPER`.  For each such act of submitting a paper, there may be a different list of `AUTHOR`s - which is M:N with `SUBMISSION`.  This M:N relationship is resolved with the `CONTRIBUTION` table.

Comment: Sir @JoelBrown what could be possible columns in Contribution Table,  What should be the primary, foreign keys for this table, also how can I ensure relation between New and Revised Submision.

Comment: @IrfanAliMemon The `Contribution` table is a pure intersection.  It would have a primary key that is composed of the combination of the two foreign keys to `Submission` and `Author`.  There is no need for any other columns in the intersection table.  New and revised submissions are implicitly related insofar as they are for the same `Paper` and therefore share the same foreign key value, e.g. `PaperID`.

Comment: Sir @JoelBrown where should I store values such Revised Submission Date, Paper Status, etc...

Comment: In 4 tables ERD, What could be the possible primary and foreign keys for the Submission table?

Comment: Sir @JoelBrown I would be grateful to you if you can post complete ERD Solution to my stated problem, with possible columns, tables, relations required for the Paper Submission  System. As Database design learner level, I am unable to model this real world system in database design.

Comment: @IrfanAliMemon - I have posted a complete ERD.  Note that primary key columns are underlined and foreign key columns are italicized.  (In the `CONTRIBUTION` table, columns are in both roles.)

Answer (score 0):

As there can be multiple authors for a single paper, so You can add one more table `Submission` where you can have attribute as

```
PaperID -- FK (PK of table Paper)
AuthorID -- FK(PK of table Author)
SubmissionDate - DateTime2
```

Rest of your design looks good. Now you can create [Unique Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190024.aspx) on columns `PaperID` and `AuthorID` in table `Submission`

```
ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueSubmission UNIQUE (PaperID , AuthorID);
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I have also submission table in my design but I was confused in selection of primary key for that table your prompt response helped me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@

This is the possible solution I have made after getting valuable feedback from Sir Joel Brown and Vijay. Kindly verify, if it is valid.

Comment: You have misapprehended, somewhat, the intention of the CONTRIBUTION table and my repurposing of your SUBMISSION table.  Please see my edited answer for clarity.